# Create a empty list. Populate the list with couple of numbers until the input is -1

Tags: python-3.x

Example for above question:
[image]

**Explanation:**
*User is giving some random input(negative and positive). i am storing all in a list and I want only positive number should be present. remove all the negative number*

**What i have tried:**

```
input_1st = []
var = int(input())


for j in range (0, var):
    ele = int(input())
    input_1st.append(ele)
    

for i in input_1st:
    if (i>0):
        lst.append(i)

print(lst)
```

**the error I have got:**

[image]

**thankyou**

Comment: You make me so confused. Why you don't just create an empty array, check if element != -1 then append to that array?

Comment: I have added an explanation to my question!!! please check

Comment: Are you actually typing all the values? because it looks like 3 goes to the first `input()`, so the the loop run only 3 iterations.

Comment: Well, so the first element is not the length of array. You must read all elements until it throws EOFError. Then you can reduce that array

Comment: can anyone add an answer? it will be helpful for me

Comment: @Guy:  yes i am typing all the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read all input and check the value.

```
result = []
while True:
    try:
        value = int(input())
        if value > 0:
            result.append(value)
    except EOFError:
        break                   

print(result)
```